# Globals page not working for admin login only

Tags: globals

When I click on my 'Globals' in my control panel area I get "This page isn't working, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS." However only that admin user login has the issue, others team users access 'Globals' with no issue.

Comment: Hi. could you give more information about the error you got when accessing the Globals using admin?

Comment: @MillerEnterprise I'd guess something specific to your computer is causing the issue? Try a couple of things... clear your browser's cookies and cache, disable all browser addons, try to load the control panel in another browser, try loading your browser in safe mode and testing the control panel again.

Comment: @MillerEnterprise Also, make sure you've applied all Craft CMS and Plugin updates so you know you're working with the most current code.

Comment: @MillerEnterprise Additionally, see if disabling ModSecurity in your hosting environment helps. If you're running cPanel, you can do this in the cPanel hosting control panel.

Comment: Great I will try all of these suggestions- thank you!